# Netbeans plugin parsing api

Tags: netbeans

How to install netbeans plugin parsing API?

Following are the Error got when I tried to install 'Scan on Demand' plugin in Netbeans:

```
    "Some plugins require plugin Parsing API to be installed.

    The plugin Parsing API is requested in implementation version 2. 

 The following plugin is affected:       Scan On Demand "
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be using an old ScanOnDemand plugin.

You can add the latest Development Plugins to your Plugins: Plugins > Settings Tab > Add and use the following URL to add a new NB Plugins source:

http://deadlock.netbeans.org/hudson/job/nbms-and-javadoc/lastStableBuild/artifact/nbbuild/nbms/updates.xml.gz

Documentation Wiki suggests that you: "Watch out! From the moment you add it you'll start receiving notifications for yet not stable updates, so you may want to check new updates carefully before installing."

Then try to install the latest Scan On Demand after the Available Plugin’s Library has been rebuilt.
Review http://wiki.netbeans.org/ScanOnDemand for more information.

Comment: Didn't work for me - I couldn't add Development Plugins repository. It's gone as soon as I close and reopen the plugins window