# FindBugs Plugin In NetBeans.

Tags: netbeans-plugins

I get the following error when I try to install FindBugs plugin in Netbeans. Can anyone help me how to resolve -

The plugin org.apache.commons.lang is requested in version 2.4.0.

The following plugin is affected:       FindBugs

Some plugins require plugin Settings API to be installed.

The plugin Settings API is requested in version >= 1.33.1 but only 1.31.1 was found.  The following plugin is affected:       FindBugs

Some plugins require plugin UI Utilities API to be installed.

The plugin UI Utilities API is requested in version >= 7.39.1 but only 7.31.2 was found.
The following plugin is affected:       FindBugs

Some plugins not installed to avoid potential installation problems.

Answer (score 0):

As it is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696448/netbeans-plugin-parsing-api), you might be using an old ScanOnDemand plugin, you can add the latest Development Plugins to your Plugins: Plugins > Settings Tab > Add and use the following URL to add a new NB Plugins source:

http://deadlock.netbeans.org/hudson/job/nbms-and-javadoc/lastStableBuild/artifact/nbbuild/nbms/updates.xml.gz

I have tried this solvation, added the source above with name 'Plugin Resource' and checked available plugins. There, Findbugs Integration plugin appeared and installed successfully. When i restarted the ide to finish the installation, it generated an error and never started again.

Thus, i have downloaded netbeans 7.3 from [this link](https://netbeans.org/downloads/) and replaced with the old one (7.0.1) on my computer. Now Findbugs plugin is availabe in the list of available plugins without any additional configuration and works flawless. I recommend you to upgrade your ide to 7.3 and solve your problem. This will fix the problems that may occure in the future because of the lack of version of your current netbeans ide.

In addition, after updating the ide, you can use the findbugs plugin installing from [this](http://bit.ly/13cUBr6) source. This plugin provides to use findbugs explicitly from the inspector.